# How to create a cross-platform class abstraction?

Tags: c++, abstraction, cross-platform

I have been struggling with how to create an "object-oriented" cross-platform abstraction.

In C++, a class requires a certain amount of coupling between its interface (i.e., public methods) and its implementation (i.e., private methods and data).

There are a few design techniques/patterns that I know of to somewhat solve this problem.  I am going to use a "mutex" as an example.  For these examples, I am defining a mutex's "interface" as having two methods with the following signatures:

```
void lock();
void unlock();
```

Ideally, I would be able to use a `Mutex` class like so:

```
#include <Mutex.hpp>

void myFunction()
{
    Mutex m;
    m.lock();
    //...
    m.unlock();
}

class MyClass
{
//...
private:
    mutable Mutex _mutex;
};
```

**Option 1: Virtual Functions**

```
//In IMutex.hpp
class IMutex
{
public:
    virtual void lock() = 0;
    virtual void unlock() = 0;
};

//In FreeRTOSMutex.hpp
class FreeRTOSMutex : public IMutex
{
//FreeRTOS implementation here
};

//In STDMutex.hpp
class STDMutex : public IMutex
{
//Implementation using std::mutex here
};
```

The problem with this is

1. It introduces the overhead of virtual methods calls (which is not usually a concern)
2. More importantly, you cannot create an instance of IMutex, so it's much more difficult to use the mutex.
3. There will only ever be one implementation of a mutex for a given compiled software/firmware, so all this overhead is completely unnecessary (i.e., runtime polymorphism is not needed)

**Option 2: PIMPL**

```
//In Mutex.hpp
class Mutex
{
public:
    void lock();
    void unlock();

private:
    class Implementation;
    std::unique_ptr<Implementation> _impl;
};

//In Mutex.cpp for FreeRTOS
class Mutex::Implementation
{
//FreeRTOS implementation here
};
void Mutex::lock()
{
    _impl->lock();
}
void Mutex::unlock()
{
    _impl->unlock();
}
```

The advantage here is `Mutex` is now a class that can be directly created (i.e., on the stack).  The disadvantage is it must use the heap (not friendly for embedded systems).  It also introduces an indirection via the pointer. So really, the disadvantages are similar to those of using virtual methods.

**Option 3: "The C++ Standard Library Way"**

The way I see it, the C++ standard library specification is, in essence, a type of abstraction.  It defines, in words and pseudocode, what classes, functions, etc... should existing in what files.  Then, it is up to the specific compiler/library implementation to make sure it provides the right files in the right places with the right contents.

So, for the mutex example, the code would just be

```
//In FreeRTOS implementation library
//In Mutex.hpp
class Mutex
{
//Implementation for FreeRTOS
};

//In STD implementation library
//In Mutex.hpp
class Mutex
{
//Implementation for std::mutex
};
```

It is then up to the user to include and link the correct implementation.

The disadvantage of this method is there is no formal (i.e., in code) description of the interface for `Mutex`.  Thus, when writing code that uses `Mutex`, it must be using at least some implementation.

---

My question is, are there other solutions I have not considered?

Comment: Do you ever use more than one of them in the same program? Does the same program run on STD **and** FreeRTOS?

Comment: @user253751 No, the system would only ever use ONE implementation.  But the code built upon these pieces needs to work for both (i.e., be generic enough that it uses the abstractions only).

Comment: then why not simply define the correct one for the current system?

Comment: @user253751 That would be my Option 3 then, would it not?

Comment: ah, yes it would

Comment: You're looking at the mechanism. That's the wrong thing to look at. It's not the interface in itself that creates an abstraction - it's *the kinds of methods* you put on the interface (or whatever the mechanism is). That is, an interface that's a thin layer over a general-purpose low level, platform-specific code doesn't really do much for you (because it's just as platform-specific and library-specific). Methods that are higher-level and that are more specific *to the domain logic of that particular application* present you with a more workable abstraction.

Comment: you're overthinking it. just do option 3

Comment: Why not use an abstract class with only virtual methods? This is how C++ does interfaces, like in C# or Java.

Comment: I guess I'm not seeing why option 1 isn't already your choice.

Comment: Somewhat unrelated to the intent of your question, but please don't manually lock and unlock the mutex, use something like std::lock_guard so you can't forget to unlock the mutex, so that the mutex will get unlocked even if an exception is thrown while it is locked, etc. Also, you could use one of the C++ standard library mutexes and those are already cross-platform.

Comment: @George Yep, I know, I was just trying to come up with a "simple" example :)

Answer (score 3):

An abstract class is useful for runtime changes. Unless you need to hot-swap the running application between... operating systems? hardware? ... you don't need runtime variability here. An abstract class is not the best tool for the job, but it would work. However, there is another way. Separate the header and implementation files in C++. Define the public interface in Mutex.hpp:

```cpp
class Mutex
{
public:
    void lock();
    void unlock();
}
```

Then create implementation-specific versions to satisfy each platform that implements the methods in the header.

In: Platforms/FreeRTOS/Mutex.cpp

```cpp
class Mutex
{
public:
    void lock() {
        // FreeRTOS implementation
    }

    void unlock() {
        // FreeRTOS implementation
    }
}
```

Create a sub folder per platform, and write a Mutex.cpp in each one. At build time, link the proper `.cpp` file based on the platform being targeted. This is pretty standard fare for C++ and C. You get a strongly-typed class without the overhead of virtual method calls. The decision gets made at compile time, rather than runtime.

Comment: I like this idea. My only question is, how do you handle the case where the class definition needs different members (e.g., private variables) depending on the platform?

Comment: This is where my C++ gets a little fuzzy. There must be a way to define the public members in a header file, but keep the non-public members in an implementation file. I tried searching for **c++ multiple header files for one class** and stumbled across this: https://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/class-code-and-header-files/ — basically you need to separate the definition from the implementation of the class. This is pretty basic C++, from what I remember, but I haven't written any C++ since college. And I don't want to tell you how many years ago that was.

Comment: @PatrickWright If you don't want to have to recompile dependent code when mutex implementation details change, you're going to have to use the Pimpl pattern. Otherwise, the typical approach would be to guard platform-specific stuff behind ifdefs. The preprocessor is not perfect, but it's very useful for this kind of compile-time feature selection.